# It is possible to pass query as a parameter to SSRS Report?

Tags: reporting-services, axapta

I have to generate a report for a list page, than means from the listpage, I will create a button that call the report.

In the report I will have the same data that I have in the form.

Answer (score 0):

You have several easy options:

1. Use Ctrl-p from the form will give you easy access to the table fields (`element.print()` by code)
2. Use Excel, mark records and press the excel button, then print from Excel.
3. [Change the query for the SSRS report](http://msdax.wordpress.com/2012/05/01/how-to-set-the-query-range-on-a-ssrs-report/)

Comment: Thank's for your answer, but i want to get more fields than the auto report can show , its amounts that calculated and not displayed in my lista page cause of performance.

Comment: Could you make the extra fields as display methods?

Comment: yes , without problems , i have one field its shown tahnks to display methos , can u esxplain plz what ca i do ????

Comment: Put them in the AutoReport field group along with the fields. Then use Ctrl-P.

Comment: but in this group i can't add a field based on display method

Comment: You can add fields and display methods.